# "It is notified for general information that" usage

Tags: word-usage, legalese

I've seen this phrase used in Government Gazettes of different countries. I have a feeling that it's a formal and **old-fashioned** expression used in legal writing, which is not in use anymore and never used by native speakers of English when speaking.

Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like something a native speaker would say casually. If you cannot find this phrase in equivalent modern documents, you can conclude that it's not commonly used. It's impossible to say if it's never used.

Comment: It's still used in official sources in the English speaking world, as Google will tell you, e.g. [Australia](https://www.gg.gov.au/sites/default/files/2020-04/australian_service_medal_declaration_determination_2012_clasp_south_sudan.pdf). It would be an odd thing to say in conversation, although a public official might read out a proclamation including the words. Not sure there's much to add beyond what the OP already has guessed.

Comment: I'd expect say "This is a Government health warning...." (UK)

Comment: It's an idiomatic use of _notify_ with passive, in official announcements only. Normally _notify_ requires a human receiver, who gets passivized (_He was notified by mail_) and a DO _that_ clause or an _of_ phrase to express the content of the notification. Here we have a passive extraposition with dummy _it_ functioning as subject, and the passivized subject _that_ clause packed off to the end. The addressee never appears except by implication in _for general information_. Got all the hallmarks of post-Victorian swinge cringe.

Comment: I don't think it conveys "old-fashioned" so much as "colonial" ("officialese" as used in ex-British Empire countries where English is the/an *official* language, but the population aren't native Anglophones).

Comment: You're right, @FumbleFingers, "colonial" is more precise.